# Disable "[Message clipped] View entire message" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is there anyway to increase the displayable size of emails to avoid the annoying "Message Clipped" additional step in Gmail?

> [Message clipped] View entire message

---

Desktop:

[image: [Message clipped] View entire message]

---

Mobile:

[image: VIEW ENTIRE MESSAGE]

Comment: I actually never saw that. Open up in a new window? Ctrl + minus?

Comment: [To ensure that messages load quickly, Gmail displays only a portion of the text of long messages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9377?hl=en).  Ctrl + minus won't change anything (the limit is based on the number of characters). I'm trying to avoid having to open up in a new window :)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trimless-for-google-mail/niepjjjfafhadmfdminbckmciijcaagc

Comment: Any updates on this since this is an old question?

Comment: @Adam_G Nothing changed on Gmail's side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to disable clipping in Gmail, as per [this rather new post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/ngKsQPQVOeA) on the Google Product Forum.

This web app in the Chrome store comes as recommended in the different posts:

[Trimmless for Google Mail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trimless-for-google-mail/niepjjjfafhadmfdminbckmciijcaagc)

<sub>Note: I'm not affiliated to the vendor of the app</sub>

Comment: Thanks good to know about the extension, as it solves another issue I created this distinguishing for this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54797/18147 : can you copy your sentence+link about Trimmless for Google Mail as an answer there? It would be nice as a reference. Regarding the [Message clipped] issue, basically I'm looking for some extensions as I feel it should be feasible. It looks like as of now there is no solution for it but the UI issue has been present for ever so I'm still somehow hoping for some workaround.

Comment: hey did u find a solution to this?

Comment: even more - it looks like Google is systematically locking conversations on that topic...

Answer (score 3):

I've been debugging an HTML signature - not much text at all - and eventually whittled it down to a couple of M-dashes (in the opening hours text) as the culprits. Looks like GMail doesn't like them, whether they're written as `–` or `&mdash;`

So it's possible (?) that GMail's [Message clipped] is for something as innocuous as a stray character

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, I was indeed wondering how comes sometimes I get that [Message clipped] so early in the email.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the sender including soft-hyphens `–` (e.g. `&shy;` or `&mdash;`) or other dash-like characters - it's nothing to do with the size of the message, and nothing you as a recipient can fix.

The reason is probably because of a convention that email signatures and disclaimers usually come at the end of email messages after a line of one or more dashes - google is saving you from wasting time on that more-or-less useless info (which is potentially a tricky legal mistake by google - should they *really* be allowed to strip legal disclaimers???  It's not their email to change, and they don't have the owner (sender) permission to do that either...)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).