# How to can I automatically show trimmed content in Gmail e-mails?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, if there are more than one emails with the same subject, it hides some similar content and shows a "..." to show the "trimmed content":

[image]

How to can I automatically expand the trimmed content in Gmail e-mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to automatically show trimmed content in Gmail e-mails.