# Prevent Gmail from trimming 'identical' email content

Tags: gmail

My website generates automated emails for email verification.

User story:
The user didn't get the automated email, and requests a new one.
The user receives the new email along with the old email.

Since the contents are identical (except for the href path in one of the links), Gmail trims the second email with the correct link, and the user is unable to verify its email.

How can I prevent Gmail from trimming a 2nd email that has graphically the same content?

Comment: Related: [How to can I automatically show trimmed content in Gmail e-mails?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54797/354)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the message subject, e.g. include a request ID. This way, messages will not be grouped together at all.

Comment: Simple yet genius!

Answer (score 0):

I just completed a project where I put *`Email ID: {GUID}`* at the bottom of the email, font PT 6, made it italic, and light gray so it's very faint. As a bonus I also use it in my audit trails for logging emails sent (good for investigations if ever needed). Personally I love the email grouping, rather than fill up my inbox with separate emails by changing the subject (to each their own I guess). The GUID at the bottom is different every time (of course) and it will prevent Good from hiding it. It works on the gmail website. I did notice though on mobile it may still hide part of it (seems to on iOS), so test that as well. In fact, mobile is worse again. It acts like a code "diff" utility and seems to show only the different parts lol, so dumb. A great example of programmers who think they have a brilliant idea when in fact it just makes it worse for everyone else.