# Gmail doesn't show entire message

Tags: email, gmail

I have a large email message, and whether I am on Desktop/Laptop or Android app, clicking the Show Entire Message link only opens a new tab which either prompts me to sign-in to Gmail or takes me back to Inbox. Clicking Show Original also shows only the clipped version with it's html. I forwarded the email to my hotmail account but the link simply leads back to gmail. How do I view the entire message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I increase the displayable size of emails to avoid "\[Message clipped\] View entire message" in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54785/can-i-increase-the-displayable-size-of-emails-to-avoid-message-clipped-view-e)

Answer (score 1):

Gmail clips any email message that goes beyond 102kB. You can take a look at the source code of the html page, everything is there, just not in a legible format.

Fortunately, Gmail does not clip messages when formatting them for printing. So, you can click the `print` print button of your browser. You should be able to scroll to view the entire message.

Please note there is no way for the recipient to stop Gmail from clipping their messages, it is completely up to the sender and Google.

Comment: Print view still shows the "Show Entire Message" link, and clicking on it takes me to a new Tab with my inbox or the gmail login page on it.